# NullPointerException при сборке проекта на онлайн компиляторе

Tags: kotlin

Необходимо ввести число через консоль, использую `val a = readln()!!.toInt()`, в intellij IDEA всё нормально, код запускается и успешно функционирует, но при попытке запустить тот же код в онлайн компиляторе, вылетает **NullPointerException**, проблема именно в переводе строки в инт, если разделить код на две строки (сначала присвоить одной переменной значение, вводимое из консоли, а второй переменной значение первой `val string = readLine()`, но с конвертацией в инт - `stirng.toInt()`, то компилятор будет показывать ошибку именно в строке с переводом в инт.

Comment: Что за "онлайн компилятор"? Может все дело в среде исполнения (Win/Mac/Linux)?